# bash - brace expansion - expand only one match

Tags: 20.04, bash

I have these 4 folders in a specific directory:

```
example.10 example.42 example.7 example.9
```

From shell terminal, I want that this brace expansion

```
echo example.{1..9}*
```

returns only one result (no matter which one) and not all of them.

How do I get this with brace expansion?

Comment: Hello. I just looked at a large number of the questions you have posted. They all seem to be some kind of homework. This one is a good example. I do not see what you have tried. Where is your script? Are you are expecting someone to do it for you.

Comment: The script is this, a simple line of code: `echo example.{1..9}*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the expansion as array and print one array item:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob
dirs=(example.{1..9}*)
echo "${dirs[0]}"
```

or using `set` (Note: this will overwrite positional parameters if they exist):

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob
set -- example.{1..9}*
echo "$1"
```

or using `for`-loop with immediate break:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob
for d in example.{1..9}*; do echo "$d"; break; done
```

Comment: Ok, that's a very affordable approach.